# gdb can't step, but can break on lines nasm

Tags: gdb, nasm, debug-symbols

I have a file compiled with nasm, with `nasm -f elf64 -g helloworld.asm`, and here is the output of `objdump -g -d -M intel helloworld.o`:

```
helloworld.e:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <_start>:
  4000b0:       b8 04 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x4
  4000b5:       bb 01 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0x1
  4000ba:       48 b9 d8 00 60 00 00    movabs rcx,0x6000d8
  4000c1:       00 00 00
  4000c4:       ba 0b 00 00 00          mov    edx,0xb
  4000c9:       cd 80                   int    0x80
  4000cb:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
  4000d0:       bb 00 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0x0
  4000d5:       cd 80                   int    0x80
helloworld.asm:
/* file helloworld.asm line 9 addr 0x4000b0 */
/* file helloworld.asm line 10 addr 0x4000b5 */
/* file helloworld.asm line 11 addr 0x4000ba */
/* file helloworld.asm line 12 addr 0x4000c4 */
/* file helloworld.asm line 13 addr 0x4000c9 */
/* file helloworld.asm line 14 addr 0x4000cb */
/* file helloworld.asm line 15 addr 0x4000d0 */
/* file helloworld.asm line 16 addr 0x4000d5 */
```

so, at least to me, it looks like it has debug information. when I run gdb, I can set a breakpoint at any line, and it breaks at the proper memory address [and every register is updated as expected] yet I cannot step, since I get the horrible

```
Single stepping until exit from function _start,
which has no line number information.
```

My gdb version is 7.7.1 and nasm version is 2.10.9.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: doesn't work with gdb 7.9 either

Comment: Does it work if you add `-F dwarf` to the nasm command line?

Comment: well, I thought I had tried it and didn't work, but now it does. I guess I mixed up somewhere, sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be, in your case, the problem is version skew between nasm and gdb.

Try to update your gdb version at least to 7.8.

Comment: i've upgraded to 7.9, and the problem remains